# what is real use of /dev/kmem char device in linux?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

From last few days, I was trying to understand the exact difference between `/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem` devices. From different sources, only thing I got to know is that when we try to read from these devices `read_mem()` and `read_kmem()` API are called respectively.

```
read_mem(): reads the *physical* memory 
read_mem(): reads the *virtual* memory as seen by the kernel.
```

I am eager to know what is the sole purpose of `/dev/kmem`, in what use-cases we can use this. `regdump` is one examplewhere `/dev/mem` is useful. But couldn't find the usefulness of `/dev/kmem`.

can someone list or share some useful information regarding the `dev/kmem` char device ?

Answer (score 1):

> can someone list or share some useful information regarding the dev/kmem char device?

The `/dev/kmem` and `/dev/mem` devices contains the same information about your RAM. But the as you can read in the [man kmem](http://linux.die.net/man/4/kmem):

```
The file kmem is the same as mem, except that the kernel virtual memory
rather than physical memory is accessed.
```

It means that `/dev/kmem` provides the same information as `/dev/mem` but as it seen by the Linux kernel. For example if you will execute execute something like this:

```
open("/dev/mem");
seek(0);
read(100);
```

You will read the first `100` bytes from the RAM address `0`. In other way if you will execute:

```
open("/dev/kmem");
seek(0);
read(100);
```

You will read `100` bytes from the `virtual address` - `0`, which is mapped by your system's memory management unit to some physical RAM address (for example `0x01000000` for the `x86_64` and you can find it with the:

`cat /proc/iomem | grep "Kernel code"`

on your device.

I think that mostly the `/dev/kmem` device can be useful for the [security](http://www.rootkitanalytics.com/kernelland/IDT-dev-kmem-method.php) research to look on process from the kernel view and I do not think that there is other important issues which you can't solve without the `/dev/kmem` for this days.

Comment: `cat /dev/kmem` results in kernel panic at my system (arch64). When I checked the more details I see that panic() was due to `copy_to_user()` try to deference the `0` address.